# Tensorflow Serving with Anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, bazel, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to get started with tensorflow serving. I have existing tensorflow installation in a conda environment and I am trying to get tensorflow serving working in same environment with [this tutorial](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_inception).

However, bazel build files always refer to global python. How do I fix this issue? Is there a way to make it work with conda environment and packages installed in it?

EDIT:
I checked bazel make environment variables using command `bazel info --show_make_env` which shows `PYTHON_BIN_PATH: /usr/bin/python`. How do I make it use conda virtual environment path?

Answer (score 0):

In case this is still actual, Bazel allows to set [environment variables](https://bazel.build/designs/2016/06/21/environment.html). Add

```
--action_env=PYTHON_BIN_PATH=path/to/anaconda/python
```

to your `~/.bazelrc`.